# How to determine if an SSIS package (.dtsx) was created by BIDS 2005 or 2008?

Tags: sql-server, ssis

Is there a sure way to determine if a .dtsx file was created using BIDS 2005 or BIDS 2008?

If it needs to be known, I'll be opening the packages with BIDS 2008. But I'd like to know before hand if it was originally created through BIDS 2005. Imagine that I don't have documentation and I'm going to be responsible for documenting the tons of SSIS packages we have. Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. There is a `DTS:Name="PackageType"` in your DTSX. Compare your value with the enum from MSDN : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.dts.runtime.dtspackagetype.aspx

A `<DTS:Property DTS:Name="PackageType">5</DTS:Property>` means BIDS 2008.

Comment: On my System both 2005/2008 display DTS:Name="PackageType 0

Comment: The enum value correspond either to DTSDesigner90 (3) or DTSDesigner100 (5). If not, then it was created by other tools than BIDS and the OP specifically ask for BIDS 2005 or 2008.

Comment: You are right, the packages I used came from datatransfer out of SQL-Servers and where modified in BIDS, PackageType did not change by modifikation.

Answer (score 1):

```
select    cast(BulkColumn as XML)
from    openrowset(bulk 'C:\temp\Neues Paket.dtsx',
                        single_blob) as pkgColumn;
```

I not sure

2008

DTS:Property DTS:Name="PackageFormatVersion"3/DTS:Property
DTS:ExecutableType="SSIS.Package.2

2005

DTS:Property DTS:Name="PackageFormatVersion"2/DTS:Property
DTS:ExecutableType="MSDTS.Package.1