# Upgrade SSIS packages to SSDT 2012

Tags: ssis, upgrade, sql-server-data-tools

I have created a new solution and project for integrated services in SSDT. I have imported the packages from the file system but when I right click on the folder with SSIS packages and choose to upgrade packages I can't choose any package. I don't understand why. Anyone else who have a solution for this? Do I have to do any step before upgrade all the packages?

Comment: What version of SSIS are the packages written in?

Comment: I am pretty sure it is written in SSIS 2008 - how can I check that?

Comment: Like this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13313739/how-to-determine-if-an-ssis-package-dtsx-was-created-by-bids-2005-or-2008.  Have you tried running the package without upgrading?  AFAIK, the solution gets upgraded but the actual package may not.

Comment: DTS:PackageType="5" - means 2008 then.

Comment: Do I have to fix connections before upgrade? Variables and stuff?